# Show/hide div with dynamic radio doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't get this one to work!

When I check the second radio button the divs with class name `wholesale-option` are shown. When I uncheck the radio button the divs aren't hidden. What I'm I doing wrong??

See my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meules/7h4q4wx1/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.gui-block-option:first').nextAll().addClass('wholesale-option');

    var newContainer = $('<div class="gui-spacer"></div><div class="gui-block-option"><div class="gui-field"><div class="gui-radio"><div class="tm-radio"><input type="radio" value="" name="shipment_method" id="gui-form-shipping-wholesale" class=""></div><label for="gui-form-shipping-wholesale">Ik wil graag bij mijn groothandel bestellen(Afhalen)</label></div><div class="gui-field-content"><p>text over bestellen bij groothandel</p></div></div></div>');


    $('#gui-form .gui-block-option:first').after(newContainer);
    $(".wholesale-option").hide();

    $("#gui-form-shipping-wholesale").change(function () {
        if ($(this).prop('checked', true)) {
            $(".wholesale-option").show();
        } else if ($(this).prop('checked', false)) {
            $(".wholesale-option").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

I tried things like `this.checked` and above with `.prop` but none are working.

Please help..

Comment: Will there be only 2 `radio` in the page? Or this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/7h4q4wx1/7/)** will do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/7h4q4wx1/16/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.gui-block-option:first').nextAll().addClass('wholesale-option');

    var newContainer = $('<div class="gui-spacer"></div><div class="gui-block-option"><div class="gui-field"><div class="gui-radio"><div class="tm-radio"><input type="radio" value="" name="shipment_method" id="gui-form-shipping-wholesale" class=""></div><label for="gui-form-shipping-wholesale">Ik wil graag bij mijn groothandel bestellen(Afhalen)</label></div><div class="gui-field-content"><p>text over bestellen bij groothandel</p></div></div></div>');


    $('#gui-form .gui-block-option:first').after(newContainer);
    $(".wholesale-option").hide();

    $("#gui-form").change(function () {
        if ($('.first').prop('checked')) {
            $(".wholesale-option").hide();
        } else {
            $(".wholesale-option").show();
        }
    });
});
```

There was 2 problems :

```
$(this).prop('checked', true)
```

This is not how you get the value of a property in jQuery. If you use 2 parameters, this is a setter, not a getter. So you have to use `$(this).prop('checked')`

```
$("#gui-form-shipping-wholesale").change(function () {
```

While this is valid, on some browser, the change event is not triggered for the "unselected" radio. So you can't catch the event from here. If you catch from a higher parent, it's ok.

Comment: Ok that makes a lot of sense! I checked your updated fiddle but it seems that the third and fourth radio when checked make them dissappear! I only want them to dissappear when the first radio is checked

Comment: You added `.first` as classname... missed that ;) Ok works thx..!

Comment: That's because `|` is not a valid character in an html id. So i can't do `$('#...')` to retrieves the first radio.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).prop('checked', true)` isn't comparing anything, it's assigning `true` to `this`. To compare you can just `this.checked === true`, plain Javascript is faster and in this case cleaner.

Also you should add the change listener to all radios in the group, then check which has been triggered, this is one option:

```
$(':radio').change(function () {
    if (this.value === 'core|130218|272516') {
        $(".wholesale-option").hide();
    } else {
        $(".wholesale-option").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The change event doesn't fire when an element is deselected. See [How to detect radio button deselect event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173685/how-to-detect-radio-button-deselect-event)

Also, calling `$(this).prop('checked', true)` is checking the radio button instead of just reading its `checked` property.

A solution is to detect the change on all radio elements and check explicity whether the first one is selected. http://jsfiddle.net/7h4q4wx1/14/

```
$("[name=shipment_method]").change(function () {
    if ($('#gui-form-shipping-wholesale').prop('checked')) {
        $(".wholesale-option").show();
    } else {
        $(".wholesale-option").hide();
    }
});
```