# How to get "unchecked" event from radio input in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, radio-button

I noticed that the "change" event only fires one event when the element is checked. But does not seem to fire any event when unchecked, or do I miss something?

I would like to do something on "uncheck" but that does never trigger.

Ideally, I do **not** want to save the inputs in an array and on change check which one is checked or not.

Here is an example, as you can see, "do something" never get’s fired:

```js
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("change", function(ev) {
   console.log(ev.target.checked);
    if(!ev.target.checked) console.log("do something");
});
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="type" checked="checked" value="guest" />
<input type="radio" name="type" value="walk_in" />
```

This seems so basic… maybe I overlooked something?
Thank you!

Comment: This might be of use, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173685/how-to-detect-radio-button-deselect-event

Comment: could addEventListener("select", .....);  be better for what you want?

Comment: ok, so if I see it right, there is actually never an event fired when the element state changes from checked to unchecked on an input of type radio??

Answer (score 2):

It only validate at the time of `targeted` element, not with other Element .Better use for Each function they validated all element change

```js
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(function(a) {
      a.addEventListener("change", function() {
        console.log(this.checked);
         console.log("checked radio value="+this.value);
        if (!this.checked) console.log("do something");
      })
    })
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="type" checked="checked" value="guest" />
<input type="radio" name="type" value="walk_in" />
```

Or if you need validate check and Uncheck*(like toggle)* use with `type=checkbox` instead of `radio` .

***`Radio` button not have `toggle` checkbox have `toggle`***

```js
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("change", function(ev) {
  console.log(ev.target.checked);
  if (!ev.target.checked) console.log("do something");
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="type" checked="checked" value="guest" />
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="walk_in" />
```