# Listen to uncheck event inside directive

Tags: javascript, angular, listener, angular2-directives

I have a directive on my radio inputs. I would like to listen to check AND uncheck (implied by check of other radio) events of this input.

I have tried to add this to my directive:

```
@HostListener('change') onChange(): void {
    console.log('change');
}
```

But the change event is not triggered when my input gets unchecked.

Is there a way to listen to the `checked` attribute? If not, what do you suggest?

**Edit:**

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/63tmFPm29z0WlCGRBGCI?p=preview) that demonstrates the issue... only the selected radio should be displayed in red

Comment: Please add some context: let's see the template around the directive.  Is the radio button within a form? Are you using template-driven or reactive forms etc...

Comment: why don't you monitor the state of the property the radio buttons are affecting rather than the state of the buttons themselves?

Comment: @BeetleJuice The radio inputs are in a form and I'm using reactive forms...I don't see how it would help solve the problem but if you think you might be able to help only knowing this info then I'll be more than happy to answer all your questions!

Comment: @Claies What do you mean by the state of property? What property are you talking about?

Comment: Please show the form template around the radio input

Comment: @Claies I'm using reactive forms and yes, I can listen to the property but I don't know how to do it within the directive

Comment: @BeetleJuice I'm creating a plunker...should be ready in few minutes

Comment: @Claies Please see my plunker (at the end of the question)

Comment: @BeetleJuice Please see my plunker (at the end of the question)

Comment: note that this isn't an angular specific issue, it is an HTML/Javascript issue;  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173685/how-to-detect-radio-button-deselect-event

Comment: @Claies Thanks for pointing me out a solution but this is an angular specific question because I need a solution for the directive! You keep saying to listen to ngModel but I'm using reactive forms... please fork my plunker and show how you would do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147879/discussion-between-ncohen-and-claies).

Comment: I understand the dilemma now, but I'm not 100% sure of a good solution.  I'm trying to do some research on possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be:

1. Inject the `FormControl` that owns the radio button into the directive.
2. Within the directive, subscribe to the control's `valueChanges` observable to be notified when the control's value changes
3. Each time the value changes, set or remove the desired CSS based on whether the new value of `FormControl` matches this specific radio button's value DOM property

**modified template**

```
<input... selected [control]="form.get('checkbox')"...value='1'/>
<input... selected [control]="form.get('checkbox')"...value='2'/>
```

Notice that the `control` property belongs to the directive, and that we're binding it to the specific instance of `FormControl` we're interested in

**modified Selected directive**

```
@Directive({selector: 'input[selected]'})
export class Selected implements OnChanges {
    constructor(private element:ElementRef) {}

    //instance of FormControl this radio btn belongs to
    @Input() control:FormControl;

    //Once a FormControl is bound, start listening to its changes
    //Once a change occurs, call manageClass and provide it the new value
    ngOnChanges(){
        this.control.valueChanges.subscribe(newVal=>this.manageClass(newVal));
    }

    //Compares the new value to the "value" property of the DOM radio btn
    //If they match, it means the radio btn is currently selected. 
    // Add or remove the CSS class as appropriate
    manageClass(newVal){
        let e = this.element.nativeElement;
        if(e.value===newVal) e.parentElement.classList.add('selected');
        else e.parentElement.classList.remove('selected');
    }
}
```

[**Live Demo**](https://embed.plnkr.co/uOIKt1unuk0KbIMT1VOy/)