# Radio button show/hide won't hide on other radio button clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Please run the code snippet to view an example**.

So I'm using some radio buttons and I have the third radio button have hidden content unless it's been checked but I can't get it to hide the content again when another radio button is selected.

**Screenshots**:
When selecting a radio button other than the last one, nothing shows (Works great)
[image]

When selecting the last radio button, I have it showing the below fields. (Works great)
[image]

When I go back to select another radio button, the items still show from the third radio button and I would like them hidden - What could I possibly be doing wrong with my JS?
[image]

**Here is the code**:

```js
document.getElementById('rtd3').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
        document.getElementById('form-wrapper-certain').style.display = ''
    } else {
        document.getElementById('form-wrapper-certain').style.display = 'none'
    }
});
```

```html
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio mt-3">
        <input type="radio" name="rtd[checked]" class="custom-control-input" id="rtd1" value="1" required>
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="rtd1"><i>None</i> of the personal information we have collected from you.</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio mt-3">
        <input type="radio" name="rtd[checked]" class="custom-control-input" id="rtd2" value="2" required>
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="rtd2"><i>All</i> of the personal information we have collected from you (subject to permitted exceptions).</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio mt-3">
        <input type="radio" name="rtd[checked]" class="custom-control-input" id="rtd3" value="3" required>
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="rtd3"><i>Certain</i> (but not all) personal information we have collected from you.</label>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Select what information you would like deleted.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='form-wrapper-certain' style="display:none">
        <div class="row mt-3">
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-11">
                <i>You must specify the personal information you would like us to delete:</i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-3">
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-11">
                <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="rtd3Transaction" name="rtd[3][transaction]">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="rtd3Transaction">My transaction data</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-3">
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-11">
                <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="rtd3Device" name="rtd[3][device]">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="rtd3Device">Information about my device(s) collected through cookies and other automated collection tools</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-3">
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="rtdConfirm" name="rtd[confirm]">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="rtdConfirm">I confirm that I would like not to sell your personal information to third parties.</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Selecting a different radio option will not trigger the `change` event of `rtd3`.

Comment: Look [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173685/how-to-detect-radio-button-deselect-event) you will find good info, [this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11174637/10797718) can be the one you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting a different radio option will not trigger the change event of `rtd3`. Instead, attach an event to all of the radio buttons that checks if the "certain" section should be hidden or shown.

```
const toggleCertainForm = () => {
  const formWrapper = document.getElementById('form-wrapper-certain');
  const rtd3 = document.getElementById('rtd3');
  formWrapper.style.display = rtd3.checked ? '' : 'none';
}

document.querySelectorAll('[name="rtd[checked]"]').forEach(r => 
  r.addEventListener('change', toggleCertainForm)
);
```

```js
const toggleCertainForm = () => {
  const formWrapper = document.getElementById('form-wrapper-certain');
  const rtd3 = document.getElementById('rtd3');
  formWrapper.style.display = rtd3.checked ? '' : 'none';
}

document.querySelectorAll('[name="rtd[checked]"]').forEach(r => 
  r.addEventListener('change', toggleCertainForm)
);
```

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-radio mt-3">
        <input type="radio" name="rtd[checked]" class="custom-control-input" id="rtd1" value="1" required>
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="rtd1"><i>None</i> of the personal information we have collected from you.</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio mt-3">
        <input type="radio" name="rtd[checked]" class="custom-control-input" id="rtd2" value="2" required>
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="rtd2"><i>All</i> of the personal information we have collected from you (subject to permitted exceptions).</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio mt-3">
        <input type="radio" name="rtd[checked]" class="custom-control-input" id="rtd3" value="3" required>
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="rtd3"><i>Certain</i> (but not all) personal information we have collected from you.</label>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Select what information you would like deleted.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='form-wrapper-certain' style="display:none">
        <div class="row mt-3">
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-11">
                <i>You must specify the personal information you would like us to delete:</i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-3">
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-11">
                <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="rtd3Transaction" name="rtd[3][transaction]">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="rtd3Transaction">My transaction data</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-3">
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-11">
                <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="rtd3Device" name="rtd[3][device]">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="rtd3Device">Information about my device(s) collected through cookies and other automated collection tools</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-3">
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="rtdConfirm" name="rtd[confirm]">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="rtdConfirm">I confirm that I would like not to sell your personal information to third parties.</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Given that you've tagged jQuery, here's an alternative solution that makes use of event delegation:

```
const toggleCertainForm = () => $('#form-wrapper-certain').toggle($("#rtd3").is(":checked"));
$(document).on("change", '[name="rtd[checked]"]', toggleCertainForm);
```

```js
const toggleCertainForm = () => $('#form-wrapper-certain').toggle($("#rtd3").is(":checked"));
$(document).on("change", '[name="rtd[checked]"]', toggleCertainForm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio mt-3">
        <input type="radio" name="rtd[checked]" class="custom-control-input" id="rtd1" value="1" required>
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="rtd1"><i>None</i> of the personal information we have collected from you.</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio mt-3">
        <input type="radio" name="rtd[checked]" class="custom-control-input" id="rtd2" value="2" required>
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="rtd2"><i>All</i> of the personal information we have collected from you (subject to permitted exceptions).</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio mt-3">
        <input type="radio" name="rtd[checked]" class="custom-control-input" id="rtd3" value="3" required>
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="rtd3"><i>Certain</i> (but not all) personal information we have collected from you.</label>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Select what information you would like deleted.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='form-wrapper-certain' style="display:none">
        <div class="row mt-3">
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-11">
                <i>You must specify the personal information you would like us to delete:</i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-3">
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-11">
                <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="rtd3Transaction" name="rtd[3][transaction]">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="rtd3Transaction">My transaction data</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-3">
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-11">
                <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="rtd3Device" name="rtd[3][device]">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="rtd3Device">Information about my device(s) collected through cookies and other automated collection tools</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-3">
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="rtdConfirm" name="rtd[confirm]">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="rtdConfirm">I confirm that I would like not to sell your personal information to third parties.</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Tyler, this is super clean!

Answer (score 0):

This change action:

```
document.getElementById('rtd3').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
        document.getElementById('form-wrapper-certain').style.display = ''
    } else {
        document.getElementById('form-wrapper-certain').style.display = 'none'
    }
});
```

is only trigger when the event **change** is call in that especific Radio Button (the one with id "rtd3") but not in the other two Radio Buttons.

One possible solution is to reproduce this behavior for the other two Radio Buttons like:

```
document.getElementById('rtd1').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
        document.getElementById('form-wrapper-certain').style.display = 'none'
    }
});

document.getElementById('rtd2').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
        document.getElementById('form-wrapper-certain').style.display = 'none'
    }
});
```

Or try to use a different aproach, I hope this help.

Comment: Thanks @Luis Miguel, this worked for now - Will be looking at alternative things to narrow down the code down the road.

Comment: @SaintLouisEvents i am glad it helps, is not a great solution and definitely you should narrow down the code but it does the work ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Hello SaintLouis Events,

In this case I think you are missing one of the main properties of both checkboxes and radio buttons which is `checked`.

What I would do is something like this:

```js
$("#rtd1").click(function() {
    if($(this).prop("checked")) {
        // this runs when the #rtd1 element is checked
        $("#form-wrapper-certain").hide();
        $("#form-wrapper-certain input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", false);
        // If you want you can also disable those checkboxes
        $("#form-wrapper-certain input[type='checkbox']").prop("disabled", true);
    }
});

$("#rtd2").click(function() {
    if($(this).prop("checked")) {
        // this runs when the #rtd2 element is checked
        $("#form-wrapper-certain").hide();
        $("#form-wrapper-certain input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", true);
        // This second line is optional, I assume you are sending all your checkboxes
        // besides from sending the #rtd2 element
        // If you want you can also enable those checkboxes if they have been disabled
        $("#form-wrapper-certain input[type='checkbox']").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});

$("#rtd3").click(function() {
    if($(this).prop("checked")) {
        // this runs when the #rtd3 element is checked
        $("#form-wrapper-certain").show();
        $("#form-wrapper-certain input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", true);
        // This second line depends on the behavior you want to achieve
        // you can either check all as initial state or uncheck all as initial state
        // If you want you can also enable those checkboxes if they have been disabled
        $("#form-wrapper-certain input[type='checkbox']").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

The `if($(this).prop("checked"))` check could be optional as radio buttons would always be checked on click, unless they are disabled.

Also, I see that your example is in JavaScript, but you mention jQuery in your tags so I made my example in jQuery.

**UPDATE**

Changed `$(this).is(":checked")` to `$(this).prop("checked")` to keep the example using jQuery and be more similar to original question.

Comment: `this.checked` is preferable to `$(this).is(':checked')`.  The pseudoselector `:checked` is primarily used for selectors.  In this usage you don't need it.  You already have `this` with the native `checked` property, supported by all browsers.

Comment: @Taplar thanks for that observation. I changed `is(':checked')` to `.prop('checked')`.

Comment: Again, `this.checked` is supported by all browsers in this day and age.  There is no reason to take a native object, instantiate a jQuery object, and call a method to get a property, when the property is already available.  That extra overhead is completely unnecessary.  jQuery is helpful and can do many things, but you should always be wary of falling into the pitfall of "jQuery must do everything" mindset.